# W3C Markup Validation errors with jQuery

Tags: jquery, w3c-validation

Running a validation on my pages where I used jQuery gives me lots of errors..
I escaped the closing tags but keep getting errors.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#main").html('<p>hello world<\/p>'); 
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you use XHTML as DOCTYPE you should wrap js-code which contains HTML fragments with CDATA

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        /*<![CDATA[*/
        $("#main").html('<p>hello world</p>');
        /*]]>*/
    });
</script>
```

Why?: [Mozilla Dev: Properly Using CSS and JavaScript in XHTML Documents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Properly_Using_CSS_and_JavaScript_in_XHTML_Documents)

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#main").html('<p>hello world</p>'); 
    });
//]]>
</script>
```

[You can read a bit more on the topic here](http://javascript.about.com/library/blxhtml.htm). The basics are that Javascript tags are CDATA elements normally, PCDATA with XHTML (so it looks inside), to be safe they need to be marked up in this way.